# Shopping cart rule

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, catalog-price-rules, catalog-rules

I'm using CE Magento 1.9.0.1, and i'm intending to do a promotion for a specific category. For instance,

2 products for $68.00 instead of u.p. S$90.00

I've tried to play around with the rules in shopping cart rules but unable to do so. Anyone have any advice? I heard that CE doesn't support this function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by doing the following when creating a Shopping Cart Price Rule:

**Conditions tab**:
If **ALL**  of these conditions are **TRUE** :

If **total quantity**  **equals or greater than**  **2**  for a subselection of items in cart matching **ALL**  of these conditions:

Category  **is**  **8** //*Your category number*  

**Actions Tab:**
Select discount amount e.g 10%

If **ALL** of these conditions are **TRUE** :
Category  **is  8** //*Your category number*

This will ensure that only the products in category 8 will be discounted.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Rule Information tab:

a) Rule Name

b) select Status

c) Select Websites

d) Customer Groups

e) Select Coupon: Specific Coupon

f) Add your coupon code or auto generated coupon code

g) 'Uses per Coupon' field as per your requirement

h) 'Uses per Customer' field as per your requirement

i) 'From date' & 'to Date': you can leave blank if you want always apply this coupon on the cart.

Conditions tab:
                If ALL of these conditions are TRUE :

Actions tab:

a) apply: as per your requirement

b) Discount amount: as per your requirement

c) If ALL of these conditions are TRUE:

Category is 3     // category id may be different.

Hope, it will be helpful.